# Debug Node and Client Javascript together

Tags: javascript

I am developping a Node, Express, Mongo, Vanilla Javascript application. I dont use React or Angular etc. because I want to simulate MVC only with SPA and data binding. My development machine is Ubuntu 20, but... I work on a Windows 10 laptop with SSH so I can connect and develop on the Ubuntu 20 machine with my Windows 10 laptop.

I did not know how to debug Node and Client Javascript in VS Code with SSH enabled. I came up with this in my launch.json file. Is this any good? It works but I can not get pwa-msedge and pwa-chrome working, dont know why, I give up...

```
    // debug node backend
    {
        "type": "pwa-node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Node",
        "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
        "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",            
        "restart": true,
        "args": ["--experimental-json-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node, ${workspaceFolder}/app.js"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },

    // debug javascript front end with chrome
    {
        "type": "chrome", 
        "request": "launch",    
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "https://localhost:4443",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you're trying to launch Chrome/Edge on your Ubuntu 20 machine, which I'll assume is running headless. Therefore Chrome/Edge just can't run. I'm also assuming you're using the Remote SSH feature of VS Code, where VS Code runs on the server but uses your laptop for the UI.

In that case, I can think of two possible solutions:

- Forward X11, allowing Chrome/Edge to run on the server but be rendered (and interacted with) locally. Since X11 forwarding isn't the most performant, this can get quite annoying.
- Launch Chrome/Edge locally with port forwarding:

  - Run Chrome with the [`--remote-debugging-port=9222`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) flag.
  - Remote port forward your 9222 port, allowing VS Code (running on the server) to attach to your Chrome instance through this port.
  - Local port forward the server's 4443 port, allowing your local Chrome instance to access the Node process running on your server.

There might be other solutions, though. For example, if your working machine does support a GUI which you can remote control, use that.

Comment: I did not have to set --remote-debugging-port, I just used the launch Chrome option of code. Thats the attach solution. Exec browser with that flag and then run code with Attach. I tried that too but did not work. I did forward port 4443 and node debugging works. Forward port Browser opens on client and can debug Javascript, code opens tunnel port. I think for debugging. This did not work with pwa versions. May be code client javascript debug over SSH is buggy because i did not find good working for this. The /public in webroot is important because in express thats where the static files live.